# Get the street name and number of an address using regular expressions in Bigquery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have a bunch of addresses that they don't look very similar between them. For example, I could have

```
STREET NAME 12501 -ADP 11 LT P 1 -A , PS 1 Y ZOC
```

or

```
av some avenue 5640 j aguirre conchali
```

Usually, the string starts with the street name and is followed by its number. How can I get all characters until the first number, but including the number?

For example:

```
av some avenue 5640 j aguirre conchali --> av some avenue 5640

STREET NAME 12501 -ADP 11 LT P 1 -A , PS 1 Y ZOC --> STREET NAME 12501

pje. 27 de abril 5492 --> pje. 27 de abril 5492 (in this case, the street name corresponds to the date April 27th)

1 poniente 643, valparaiso --> 1 poniente 643 (in this case, the street name is "1 poniente")
```

I'm trying to do this in `BigQuery`, using `REGEXP_EXTRACT`, but not having a lot of success for now.

Comment: You'll need to define one regex per format and use a boolean separator to make one big `OR` statement like this `format1|format2|format3|format4`

Comment: But this is still using `REGEXP_EXTRACT` or should I switch to `REGEXP_CONTAINS` and perform the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` where `REGEXP_CONTAINS` is true? And this approach suggests that each format should use different column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT('column', '^((?:\D*(?:\d{2}\s+de\s+\w+\s+\d{4})|\d+)?\D*\d*)')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/LIZeOp/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                                 (1 or more times (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        de                       'de'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                                 (1 or more times (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
                                 (1 or more times (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                                 (1 or more times (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: Thank very much! Your answer is great! If I understood this, in order to incorporate other special words besides `de`, I should add something like `de|la|el` or it should be `de+la+el`? Also, where did you learnt regexp. I need to incorporate this things under my belt.

Comment: @PedroPabloSeverinHonorato Yes, `(?:de|la|el)`.